# store the user entered data in html table as a array variable for each column of the table when user submit the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a html table with multiple rows where user can enter few field details like Sprint,Role,Project,Comments 
and remaining fields SID,Project Code
are retrieved from backend when user click on getDetails button...User can enter data in all the existing 7 rows of 
table 
or can enter in only few rows and click on getDetails button. I want to store the user entered data for each column in a 
separate array varaible so that i can pass this array to my backend functinality..

Sample Demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/wqvUY58921gzSp1RpUqJ?p=preview

I have seen samples where they are showing array values in the table but my requirement is to store the user entered data for each column in a separate table.
Sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        function submitData(){
          alert("submit");
        var sprintFieldArray = [];
        var roleFieldArray =[];
        var projectFieldArray = [];

        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body>

<table id="productTable" border="1">

    <tr>
        <th>Sprint <span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
        <th>Role<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Project<span style="color:red;">*</span></th>
        <th>SID</th>
        <th>Proj Code</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    
         </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select class="sprint" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">121.1</option>
                <option value="">121.2</option>
                <option value="">121.3</option>
                <option value="">122.1</option>
                <option value="">122.2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="role" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Comments" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="project" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="">ProA</option>
                <option value="">ProB</option>
                <option value="">ProC</option>
                <option value="">ProD</option>
            </select>
        </td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>
         <td><!--dynamic value is shown when user enter mandatory fields and click on getDetails button--></td>    </tr>
        <tr>

</table> <br>
<input type="submit" value="getDetails" onclick="submitData()">
</body>
</html>
```

If user enters only first 5 rows of information in the table, i want to store values for fields sprint,role and project columns in a array in 3 different variables for the 5 rows..

```
 var sprintFieldArray = [];
        var roleFieldArray =[];
        var projectFieldArray = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're ultimate goal is still unclear, in why you want to save these all to separate arrays, which disassociates the values from each other, but here you go.

```js
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener(
  'submit',
  function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var sprintFieldArray = [];
    var roleFieldArray = [];
    var projectFieldArray = [];
    var sprints = this.getElementsByClassName('sprint');
    var roles = this.getElementsByClassName('role');
    var projects = this.getElementsByClassName('project');
    
    for (i = 0; i < sprints.length; i++) {
      var e = sprints[i];
      sprintFieldArray.push(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)
    }

    for (i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
      var e = roles[i];
      roleFieldArray.push(e.value);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
     var e = projects[i];
      projectFieldArray.push(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)
    }

    console.log('sprintFieldArray', sprintFieldArray);
    console.log('roleFieldArray', roleFieldArray);
    console.log('projectFieldArray', projectFieldArray);
  }
);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <section>
    <input type="text" class="role">
    <select class="sprint">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="121.1">121.1</option>
      <option value="121.2">121.2</option>
      <option value="121.3">121.3</option>
      <option value="122.1">122.1</option>
      <option value="122.2">122.2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="project" >
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="ProA">ProA</option>
      <option value="ProB">ProB</option>
      <option value="ProC">ProC</option>
      <option value="ProD">ProD</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <section>
    <input type="text" class="role">
    <select class="sprint" >
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="121.1">121.1</option>
      <option value="121.2">121.2</option>
      <option value="121.3">121.3</option>
      <option value="122.1">122.1</option>
      <option value="122.2">122.2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="project" >
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="ProA">ProA</option>
      <option value="ProB">ProB</option>
      <option value="ProC">ProC</option>
      <option value="ProD">ProD</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```